# Background image is not visible if background of above of view is set

Tags: android

I am working on android app where I want to design layout such that "Success" image (20%) - Linearlayout should be top layout and 60%(RelativeLayout) should be in center layout and 20%(LinearLayout) should be on bottom layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grey_background"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/trans_status_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/sucessfull" />

                    <in.xxx.utils.RobotoMediumTextView
                        android:id="@+id/trans_status"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Transaction Successfull"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <!--<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                   >-->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bill_top" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp">

                        <in.xxx.utils.RobotoMediumTextView
                            android:id="@+id/bene_name"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <in.xxx.utils.RobotoMediumTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/sender_mobile"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                    android:gravity="center"

                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Mobile No."
                                    android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <in.xxx.utils.RobotoMediumTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/bene_acc_no"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                    android:gravity="center"

                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="A/C No."
                                    android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <in.xxx.utils.RobotoMediumTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/trans_mode"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                    android:gravity="center"

                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Type"
                                    android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <in.xxx.utils.RobotoMediumTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/bene_ifsc"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                    android:gravity="center"

                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="IFSC"
                                    android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/dark_grey"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/card_view"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                            card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/status_stamp"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                    android:src="@drawable/success"
                                    />


                                <FrameLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:padding="10dp">

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                                        android:orientation="vertical">

                                        <LinearLayout
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                                            <TextView
                                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:text="Transfer Amount:"
                                                android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                                                android:textSize="11sp" />

                                            <in.xxx.utils.RobotoMediumTextView
                                                android:id="@+id/amount"
                                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                                        </LinearLayout>

                                        <View
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                            android:background="@color/grey_background" />

                                        <LinearLayout
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                                            <TextView
                                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:text="Transfer Charges:"
                                                android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                                                android:textSize="11sp" />

                                            <in.xxx.utils.RobotoMediumTextView
                                                android:id="@+id/charges"
                                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                                        </LinearLayout>

                                    </LinearLayout>

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                                        android:orientation="vertical">


                                        <in.xxx.utils.RobotoMediumTextView
                                            android:id="@+id/amount_total"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                                            android:textSize="24sp"
                                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                                            android:text="Total Amount"
                                            android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                                            android:textSize="11sp" />
                                    </LinearLayout>
                                </FrameLayout>


                            </FrameLayout>


                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <in.xxx.utils.RobotoMediumTextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="15dp"
                            android:text="Transaction details"

                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />


                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/trans_list"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                            android:divider="@null"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"

                            android:paddingTop="8dp"

                            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bill_bottom"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <!--
                                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Please check]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description briefly so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide the screen on the percentage basis, take LinearLayout as root and then use weight to divide the whole screen in the ratio as needed.

To bring the view on top, after your view is created and attached, add this line:

```
view.bringToFront();
```

Comment: thanks, but it hide my text of center layout, it should hide text.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful of the result and of the expectation.